# What is $\mathbb{Z}(n)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I read it in the above context (from the book "Endomorphism Rings of Abelian Groups"). Hence $\mathbb{Z}(n)$ is an abelian group. However it is not being defined in the book itself.

I am guessing $\mathbb{Z}(n)$ is the same as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ considered as an abelian group?

Is there such a result $\text{End}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}_n$?

Thanks.

Comment: How can we tell? You omitted the definition of $\Bbb Z(n)\ \ddot\frown$.

Comment: I read it in the book "Endomorphism Rings of Abelian Groups". I did a text search in the book, it seems not defined in the book.

Comment: From the result and the proof I'd say your guess is accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, indeed, $\mathbb{Z}(n)$ seems to be $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as an abelian group, since if you look at the next line, it says that there is a generator meaning that the group is cyclic. My guess is that the author uses this notation to make clear that this is an abelian group, and distinguish it from the **ring** $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

The fact that End$(\mathbb{Z}(n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is very general (this can be seen as a very special case of the [enriched](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+Yoneda+lemma) Yoneda embedding for example).

A less extreme generalization is as follows: given any ring $R$, we can consider $R$ to be an $R$ module, and then End$(R) \cong R$ as a ring. This is just the case $R = \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I think it is worth pointing out that the isomorphism is not as general as it might seem. It is only a special case of the ring situation because it happens that all group homomorphisms are ring homomorphisms. This will fail for other abelian groups.

Comment: Woops, I actually meant module, rather than ring, in the above.

Comment: Well, right, I'm implicitly equating $\mathbb{Z}$-modules with abelian groups, and since this particular $\mathbb{Z}$-module is $n$-torsion, it is actually a $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ module.

Comment: Right, but there can be several ways to turn an abelian group into a ring. And in general, there will be many more endomorphisms as a group than as a module over itself.

Comment: I see, I guess I wasn't viewing it as turning the abelian group into a ring and then giving it a module structure, but rather I was just using the modules structure it already naturally had. You are right that if one wants to stick to abelian groups rather than modules, then you don't get much further generalizing.